# Yii2 - Ajax ActiveForm validation don't show errors

Tags: json, ajax, yii2

I have 5 different models in a form to be validate with ajax in a single controller :

```
public function performAjaxValidation($model1, $model2, $model3, $model4, $model5) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validateMultiple([$model1, $model2, $model3, $model4, $model5]);
}
```

For each models, i have a 'unique' rule like :

```
[['COUNTRY_LABEL'], 'required',
    'when' => function ($model) {
        return ($model->COUNTRY_ID == 0) || is_null($model->COUNTRY_ID);
    }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
        return ($('#country-country_id').val() == 0) || ($('#country-country_id').val() == \"\");
    }"],   

[['COUNTRY_LABEL'], 'unique', 'message' => 'Country already exist.')],
```

and more...

And a single view :

```
            <?php
            $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                        'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',],
                        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            ]);
            ?>
            <?= $form->field($countryModel, 'COUNTRY_LABEL')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

JSON works fine and i can see on my view the 'cannot be blank' message.
When i want to test if 'COUNTRY_LABEL' is unique, JSON return 'country already exist' but dont show me the message in the view.

What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to configure an `id` in your form:

```php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'contact-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
]);
```

You also need to prepare the server so that it can handle the AJAX validation requests. This can be achieved by a code snippet like the following in the controller actions:

```php
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```

And finally, this is how I use to handle the returned json results in my view (in this case, iterating `data` to fill a select field):

```php
        $.post('" . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('some/action') . "', {id: $('#someform-attrib_id').val()}, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, obj) {
               someSelect.append($('<option>').val(obj.id).text(obj.name));
            })
        });
```